# FullCalendar - adding events dynamically not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

Dynamic data is not being added to the events in fullCalendar. I am using AJAX here to get a response and I store it in my "events" array:

```
events: function () {
    var events = [];
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: '/employee/leave/2',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: '',
      success: function (doc) {
        console.log(doc)

        if (doc != null) {
          events.push({
            id: doc.id,
            title: doc.reason,
            start: "2018-5-22",
            // end: doc.to_date
          });
        }
      }
    });
},
```

Comment: To get a valid answer, it's better to provide an example JSON from your response. Also, did you check your console log? Are there any JS or network related errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite straightforward if you follow the documentation accurately and fully.

The description at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function makes it clear that the events function has a number of important parameters supplied to it.

The "start", "end" and "timezone" parameters are for you to send to your server to tell it to restrict the results to the dates actually being displayed on the calendar currently (fullcalendar will make another request to the server for more events if the user moves to another date range, e.g. the next month). This is technically optional, so if it's not important to your use case you can ignore them.

However the "callback" parameter is very important. This contains a function which you must call when you have fetched your events, and pass it the list of events. This is the mechanism by which you give the events you've fetched to fullCalendar in order to display them. If you don't do this, nothing will ever be displayed.

So simply change your code to this:

```
events: function( start, end, timezone, callback ) { //include the parameters fullCalendar supplies to you!

  var events = [];

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/employee/leave/2',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: '',
    success: function (doc) {
      console.log(doc)

      if (doc != null) {
        events.push({
          id: doc.id,
          title: doc.reason,
          start: "2018-5-22",
          // end: doc.to_date
        });
      }

      callback(events); //you have to pass the list of events to fullCalendar!
    }
  });
},
```

P.S. Your example above involves only adding one event to the calendar, and you're assuming that the JSON only includes one events. That may be fine and what you wanted, but it does sound a little unlikely in real life, so you may want to consider whether that's a good approach, or whether you should be returning a list of events from your server.